# Constraint layout with stretchable view

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to build responsive layout, but I am unable to do so. I need to implement view logic presented on those drawings:
[image]
(from the bottom) There is a View with fixed size, anchored to the bottom of the screen. Above it there is a TextView. Its minimum height should be space between center guideline and bottom view. When there is a lot of text it should grow above the center guideline. On the top there is an ImageView with maximum height as space between screen top and center guideline and no minimum height. My current solution looks something like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="barrier" />

    <Textview
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="bottomView" />

    <View
        android:layout_height="{some}dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="guidelineCenter,textView" />
<ConstraintLayout>
```

At this point a case with long text works fine, but if text is short I end up with text anchored to the bottom view. Any idea how force this minimum constraints required for left image?

Comment: Is it compulsory to implement `ConstraintLayout` ?

Comment: @nimi0112 No, but I am trying to use it as much as I can to learn it. If you know how to achieve it with any other layout please share.

Comment: Yeah learning is good. But if you get struck It can be achieved through Linear layout by setting `weight` of the both the layout's programatically based on your logic

Comment: @nimi0112 Yes, left screen is easy to achieve with `LinearLayout`, but I don't think that right one is possible then.

Comment: It is possible just instead of assigning them equal `weights` set their `weights` for right image as `0.2 (ImageView)` and `0.8(Textview) ` based on your logic

Comment: @nimi0112 This requires knowing exact weight values. So I would have to calculate and apply them programatically.

Comment: No, It's simple just treat it as a ratio on a scale of `0 to 1`  and choose your ratio as you like....

Comment: @nimi0112 The thing is I don't know the ratio. I just have an image and some text of unknown length.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170993/discussion-between-nimi0112-and-tiero).

Comment: Can you edit your question and add any other layout will also work so that I can post this as an answer. If later you get any other good answer you can accept that...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way through XML to defined a percentage minimum height, so you will have to enforce a minimum height in code. Here are two images that show a short amount of text and one with a longer amount. The red line is there to show where the 1/2 way point is and is not needed. The guideline set at 50% is also not needed.

[image: [image 1]]

[image: [image 2]]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:text="This is big text "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottomView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.xml**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;
    private TextView mTextView;
    private View mBottomView;
    private int mMinHeight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        mBottomView = findViewById(R.id.bottomView);
        mTextView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.large_text).substring(0, 1000));

        mLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mMinHeight = mLayout.getHeight() / 2 - mBottomView.getHeight();
                if (mTextView.getHeight() < mMinHeight) {
                    mTextView.setMinHeight(mMinHeight);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this slightly different, but also with kotlin/java code.